# Showing that if $T \in \mathcal{J}^k(V)$ then $\text{Alt}(T) \in \mathcal{J}^k(V)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Showing that if $T \in \mathcal{J}^k(V)$ then $\text{Alt}(T) \in \mathcal{J}^k(V)$.

I have the proof here: [image]

What I don't understand is why the author is defining $w_j$ like that, additionally, we have on the first line that $\text{Alt(T)}(v_1,...,av_i + bv_i',...,v_k) = \sum \text{sgn}(\sigma)T(w_{\sigma(1)},...,w_{\sigma(k)})$ why are we permuting $w$ and not $v$?

Answer (score 0):

One needn't get smothered in sums and permutations. You can go by steps. Take a $k$-multilinear transformation $T$. Given a permutation $\sigma$ of $[k]$, let $\sigma$ be the corresponding linear transformation that  permutes $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ according to $\sigma$. It should be clear this is linear. Thus if $T\sigma$ is also linear, and ${\rm Alt}(T)$ is obtained by taking a scalar sum of $T\circ \sigma$; namely $${\rm Alt}(T)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_k} (-1)^\sigma T\sigma$$

Comment: Thanks, I follow that - but I still don't understand specifically what the author has done here. Could you elaborate on that please?